# Where can I find a cheap vegan protein bar?

Tags: veganism, protein

I weight lift 6 times a week as I'm trying to build muscle.  I am vegetarian but I try to limit my amount of dairy intake.

I am eating PURE Protein Bars as snacks between my regular meals. They cost about $0.90 for about 20 grams of protein.  Does anyone know of any vegan alternatives with the same amount of protein at the same low cost?  I'm in the US.

Comment: perhaps consider making your own bars or high protein cookies

Comment: Have you met with medical professionals to determine the amount of protein you require?  I can recommend Lärabars, but they do not have that quantity of protein unless you eat several of them.

Comment: Actually, allow me to correct myself.  Lärabar now manufactures high-protein bars, but I have not checked to see if they are vegan.  They also cost more than the PURE Protein Bars you are currently eating.

Answer (score 1):

I really enjoy the Kirkland signature protein bars that you can get at any Costco, but those are slightly higher in price compared to the PURE protein bars, by a few cents per 20 grams of protein.

An item like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WW7NZV7) averages at $1.40/21.5g of protein. I don't know if that's a valid answer to your question because it's not exactly cheaper but it's the only thing that comes to my mind.

Comment: the Kirkland signature protein bars contain milk, so they fail the vegan requirement

Comment: rip, Larabar/That's It is the way to go then